# How can I test if an attribute of a CoreData object is null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I want to test if an NSNumber attribute of a NSManageObject Subclass has been set or not. Note, that the attribute is of NSNumber / Integer16
I have tried several approaches but none worked (these below always evaluate to false):

```
// Note: patient.zyklus_laenge is of NSNumber (Integer16)
// does not work
id value = patient.zyklus_laenge;
if (value == [NSNull null]) {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 28];
} else {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", patient.zyklus_laenge];
}
// does not work
if (!patient.zyklus_laenge) {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 28];
} else {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", patient.zyklus_laenge];
}
// does not work
if ([patient.zyklus_laenge isEqual:nil]) {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 28];
} else {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", patient.zyklus_laenge];
}
// does not work
if (patient.zyklus_laenge == nil) {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 28];
} else {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", patient.zyklus_laenge];
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me and explain me why these are not working?

Comment: What does `patient.zyklus_laenge` return in command line, when it's nil?

Comment: NSLog shows: `patient.zyklus_laenge: (null)`

Comment: Try switching "isEqual:" with "=="

Comment: Tried already, see the last if-else, to no avail. NSLog always shows: `patient.zyklus_laenge: (null)` but the `else` branch never executes

Comment: Not NSLog, but `po patient.zyklus_laenge` in command line.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188413/storing-optional-nsnumber-in-core-data

Comment: No, this does not help in my case. Because: I am migrating from one model version to a newer. patient objects which were created before migration don't have the attribute yet. Once they migrate, the old patient objects will have `zyklus_laenge` attribute, but not set. Newly created patient objects do have the value set on creation.

Comment: Try checking if ([patient.zyklus_laenge intValue] == 0). This should return true if the value was not set before.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am still stuck..

Answer (score 0):

```
id value = patient.zyklus_laenge;
if (value == [NSNull class])
```

to

```
id value = patient.zyklus_laenge;
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

Comment: This works, but it gives me a compiler warning: Incompatible pointer types. I found a different solution, see below

Comment: Maybe he meant `[NSNull class]` ?

Comment: No, i tried that, because it seemed logical to me. But `[NSNull class]` did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the attribute in core data as required with a default value and to test with this code:

```
if (!patient.zyklus_laenge) {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 28];
} else {
    self.zyklusLaengeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", patient.zyklus_laenge];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default value set for the attribute, it will be that default value, which is normally 0, not null.

If so, you can check the following:

`if (patient.zyklus_laenge.intValue == 0)`

Otherwise, this null check can be used:

`if (patient.zyklus_laenge != nil)`