# Check if an attribute of a CoreData entity is null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to check if the attribute on a core data entity is Null or not. I tried several approaches and went through some questions on SO and surprisingly there were no answer or they didn’t work. The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611823/how-can-i-test-if-an-attribute-of-a-coredata-object-is-null) mentions all the possible ways to check the attributes value but there are no inputs that work. My app crashes when i try to check the attribute for a `Null` value. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

*EDIT*

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrStringNew = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[contact valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:10] range:boldedRange];
    titleLbl.attributedText = attrStringNew;
```

So a case where the contact has no first name, my app will crash.

Comment: ok..could you please show your code?

Comment: check in this way 

if([contact valueForKey:@"first_name"])
{
........code here
}else
{
//Handle issue here
}

Comment: done. Added in Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check in this way

```
if([contact valueForKey:@"first_name"]) 
{ ........code here }
else 
{ //Handle issue here 
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to call for your core data `Entity` like below.

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        NSFetchRequest *theRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Your Entity Name"];
  NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *resultArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:theRequest error:&error];

    if (!resultArray) {
        abort();
       //check here where the array is null or not

    }
    else
    {
        //then in here you can check the objects one by one
        for (yourEntity *entity in resultArray)
        {
            NSString *myobject = entity.first_name;
            //in here your can check the each object is null or not
           if([myobject iseEqualToString:@""])
           {
               NSLog(@"the object is null");
           }

        }
    }
```